# Getting run-time error 2465 when using Instr function

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to pull the date out of a string contained in a variable.

Variable is RWPSheetvalues(96)
RWPSheetvalues(96) contains the string "AIT_13_11_11_Metro_Sky Park 13_UR"
The date is 11/11/2013

So, I thought I would use the Instr function to remove the first few characters up to beginning of date (this could be between 3 & 5 characters - depending on string).  So the line of code is as follows:
CharPosition = InStr(1, {RWPSheetvalues(96)],"-",1)
This gives ma a run-time error of 2465.

Any ideas why the error?

Comment: Perhaps you mean to use `InStr(1,RWPSheetvalues(96),"_")` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this fancy expression:

```
ThisDate = CDate("20" & Replace(Left(Split(RWPSheetvalues(96), "_", 2)(1), 8), "_", "/"))
```

It *strips* the first part, *select* the next eight chars (the date), *replaces* _ with /, *prefix* with 20 for the century, and finally *converts* to a date value.

Comment: Could this also be an alternative? `Eval("DateSerial(" & Replace(Left(Split(RWPSheetvalues(96), "_", 2)(1),8),"_",",") & ")")`

Comment: @LeeMac: It seems so, but many, including me, prefer to keep _Eval_ as the last option as those expressions can be hard to read and, indeed, cumbersome to debug.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Split` function with an underscore delimiter, and then supply the appropriate elements to the `DateSerial` function.